# Cognito authorization code grant flow for custom UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to replicate functionality of cognito hosted ui sign in page(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html), but aws sdk does not provide any method that would take username,password and would return authorization code which could be used for obtaining access/id token. The initiateAuth and adminInitiateAuth only support implicit flow which returns directly access/id token. Is there any workaround for this, how to retrieve authorization code?

With best regards,
Jakub

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no API that supports this functionality. It would be great if `initiateAuth` and `adminInitiateAuth` could respond with authorization code.

One of the workarounds [suggested by AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=832982&#832982) is for your backend to send a POST request with login and password to the login page in the hosted UI. I wouldn't recommend this solution though. It's unnecessarily complicated and doesn't work with MFA challenges. It may also impact brute force attack detection as well as the Advanced Security features because the original IP address of the user is masked by your backend IP address.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still true or if they have updated the functionality. I couldn't find anything in the docs or on the forum posted in this answer

Comment: Also curious. It's crazy that this still isn't a thing.

Answer (score -3):

You should use some SDK. Refer this link for examples of how to in a web environemtn
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

Comment: yes I am using java sdk. The javascript sdk only provides openid implicit flow which directly returns access/id tokens, that is completely different flow

Comment: Are you on Android? Try [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-android-sdk.html). Cognito is meant only for web or mobile apps as per the docs. **Amazon Cognito provides authentication, authorization, and user management for your web and mobile apps.**

Comment: No, i need to do it from server so I am using java sdk. I want to create my own UI for login (but not SPA) so backend will do actual sign in, but I need to use authorization code grant flow.

Comment: First, setup a custom UI using Cognito JS SDK. Then implement the authorization flow.

Comment: Getting an authorization code grant with the hosted UI is not possible with any Cognito API or SDK. It's only possible by interacting with the hosted UI ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120568/451480)), which is fragile.